# How to ensure padding also affects all lines instead of just the first line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have applied some padding via Bootstrap to a span of text. However, when the line goes to the next line via < br > , the padding for that line onwards no longer applies.

The code in particular with this issue is as follows:

```
            <div class="col-sm-12 d-sm-flex d-md-inline align-items-sm-center justify-content-sm-center ">
                    <div class="py-md-20 mx-md-10">
                            <span class="py-sm-40 px-sm-20 px-md-70">
                                Before any Service or Repair we will carry out a full check of the bike to ensure the bike is safe and you <br> are getting the service that best suits you and your bike. 
                            </span>

                            <span>
                                <button class="b-button__outline text-bg-info"> Book Assessment </button>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                        </div>
```

Please note external stylesheets are needed to see exactly what is happening. Hence, https://codepen.io/nisofwareengineer/pen/ExxyoVR should help you see the problem in more detail.

The text ''are getting the service that best suits you and your bike. '' does not seem have any padding.

My objective is to make it look like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Voted to close as well since my effort of helping you by making a snippet is made undone without providing an alternative way of posting the minimal needed code to reproduce the problem. We can't help you if we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: It appears I tried editing the post in an attempt to follow Pauli_D's suggestion the same time you did. Sorry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
span {
  display: block;
}
```

or

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```